# Replacing a number in an array if duplicates are found

Tags: java, arrays, methods, replace, duplicates

Make the user enter 5 integer values into the array in the main method. Pass array into a separate function. There, check for duplicated values in the array. If duplicates are found, eliminate the duplicate integer and replace it with -1. 
Print the processed array back in the main method.. i think i know how to replace the value with -1 but how do I return the array to the main back again. The code is:

```
 package methods;
import java.util.*;
public class remdup {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 5 integers:  ");
    int [] x= new int [5];
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    x[i]=in.nextInt();
}
    check(x);
   // Insert method here 
}
    //Method check starts here...
    public static void check(int []y) {
      //  int pos = y[0];
        int len=y.length;
        int i=0;
        int j = i+1;
       for (i=0; i<len-1; i++) {
           for (j=i+1; j<len-1;j++ ) {
            if (y[i]==y[j]) {
                //how to replace numbers???
               y[i]=-1;
                System.out.println("Duplicate found");
            }
            }
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: If input array {1,4,5,1,2} out put {1,4,5,-1,2}? or {-1,4,5,-1,2}?

Comment: Actually you're not finding duplicates.. your `j` is fixed.

Comment: your code has some errors... you only see duplicates next to each other. but what about `[1,2,3,4,1]`?

Comment: The whole code in `check` function is of no use. Need to be rewritten.

Comment: i want it  {1,4,5,1,2} out put {1,4,5,-1,2}...

Comment: use a `Set<Integer>` to keep track of the numbers you already have. Iterate over your array and check if the set contains the number at your current position. if yes: replace it with -1. if no: add the number to the set.

Answer (score 3):

use a Set to keep track of the numbers you already have. Iterate over your array and check if the set contains the number at your current position. if yes: replace it with -1. if no: add the number to the set...

```
public static void check(int []y) {
    Set<Integer> foundNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();

    for(int index = 0; index < y.length; index++) {
        if(foundNumbers.contains(y[index]) {
            y[index] = -1;
        } else {
            foundNumbers.add(y[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I came here to say exactly what you said. The best solution on the page!

Comment: @Marco Forberg : though this is a old post but i think you missed adding the replaced number to the set i.e. -1 back to the set. in the if condition. The solution should be like below :  public static void check(int []y) {
     Set<Integer> foundNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();

     for(int index = 0; index < y.length; index++) {
         if(foundNumbers.contains(y[index])){
             y[index] = -1;      
            
         } 
         
         foundNumbers.add(y[index]);
     }
     
     System.out.println(foundNumbers);
 }

Comment: @AshishKathait if the condition is true that means the set already contains the number. No need to add it again

Answer (score 0):

you replace number in the array like this:

```
y[i] = -1;
```

but your check function will not work this way.

Comment: Yah! tnx but how do i return the array to the main and print??? I do not know how to return an array back to main method

Comment: you don't need to return the array to main. java is pass by value! you manipulate the actual array, not a copy of it.
If you want to print it, i would suggest ussing `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x))`

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework, I will not go into details however, if you look at your `check` function:

```
public static void check(int []y) {
      //  int pos = y[0];
        int len=y.length;
        int i=0;
        int j = i+1;
       for (i=0; i<len-1; i++) {
            if (y[i]==y[j]) {
                //how to replace numbers???
                System.out.println("Duplicate found");
            }
        } 

    }
```

You will notice that you are initially setting `j` to 1, but you are never updating its value. So in your `for` loop, you need to update the value of `j` at the end of each iteration.

You also need to include an extra loop, one which holds the current number and another one which checks the rest. Lastly, to overwrite the value you have, simply write to the array like so: `y[i] = -1`.

Comment: I did this already.. but now since i have to return the array back to main and print it there, i want a way to do it!

Comment: @user2750830: use something like so: `return y` and change `void` to `int[]` in your method signature. However, in this case, since you are not copying the array you can get away with not returning it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your whole like this way

```
   import java.util.*;
    public class test1 {
        public static void main (String[]args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 5 integers:  ");
        int [] x= new int [5];
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        x[i]=in.nextInt();
    }
        int z[]=check(x);
        for(int o=0;o<z.length;o++)
        {
            System.out.println(z[o]);
        }
       // Insert method here 
    }
        //Method check starts here...
        public static int[] check(int []y) {
          //  int pos = y[0];
            int len=y.length;
            int i=0;
            //int j = i+1;
           for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
               for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
               {
                if (y[i]==y[j]) {
                    //how to replace numbers???
                    y[i]=-1;
                   // System.out.println("Duplicate found");
                }
            } }
           for(int k=0;k<len;k++)
           {
               //System.out.println(y[k]);
           }
return y;
        }

}
```

Comment: tnx. but I was asked to return the array to the main and print it there.

Comment: @user2750830 check the this one

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 5 integers:  ");
    Map<Integer,Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
    int [] x= new int [5];
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        int val=in.nextInt();
        x[i]=val;
        Integer iniVal=map.get(val);
        if(iniVal==null){
             iniVal=0;
        }
        map.put(val,iniVal+1);
    }
    int[] y=getNewArr(x,map);
    for (int i=0;i<y.length;i++){
        System.out.println(y[i]);
    }
}
public static int[] getNewArr(int[] x,Map<Integer,Integer> map){
    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        int numElement=map.get(x[i]);
        if(numElement!=1){
          for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
             if(x[i]==x[j]){
                    x[i]=-1;
             }
          }
        }
    }
     return x;
}
```

input array: `{1,4,5,1,2}`

Output array: `{1,4,5,-1,2}`

Answer (score 0):

Though this is a very old post I think there is an error in the accepted answer. We should be adding the replaced number back to the array. However in the accepted answer we are replacing it with -1 but we are never adding it back to SET.
Below is my corrected solution :

```
    public static Set<Integer> check(int []y) {
        Set<Integer> foundNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
    
        for(int index = 0; index < y.length; index++) {
            if(foundNumbers.contains(y[index])){
                y[index] = -1;      
               
            } 
            
            foundNumbers.add(y[index]);
        }
         return foundNumbers;
        
    }
```